# Populate image size attributes dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i set  attributes for height and width dynamically? The image is served up dynamically (a random photo), but it is not always the same size. I'd like to insert the actual height and width values into the  tag so we can score a little better on a web performance report (getting marked down for not specifying the image size). Can this be done via jQuery?

Comment: Can you show your "*[MCVE]*" HTML and JavaScript/jQuery? What have you tried, where are you stuck, what goes wrong..? How are you retrieving/loading these images? And yes, this can be done via jQuery (and, of course, plain JavaScript).

Comment: Just changing height and width value inside the tag  won't bring any good if you link to an image say hello.jpg of dimensions 1024x700 and filesize 100kb so if you have `<img src='hello.jpg' height=100 and width=100>` it still loads hello.jpg of dimensions 1024x700 and filesize 100kb therefore no difference to network loading time or web performance;difference can come if you can resize that file on your server to your size and then give that as src

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about it. Sounds like unnecessary bloat for arbitrary points. What web performance report are you using? W3C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below uses jQuery to change the `width` and `height` of all images inside a `<div>` width a `class="images"`.Copy this code as is into a new page and understand how it works, then apply to your own project:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $("#btnMakeImagesSmaller").click(function () {
                MakeAllImagesSmaller();
            });

            function MakeAllImagesSmaller() {
                debugger;

                var images = $(".images img");

                for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                    ChangeSize(images[i], "100px;", "100px");
                }
            }

            function ChangeSize(element, width, height) {
                $(element).css("height", height);
                $(element).css("width", width);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="button" id="btnMakeImagesSmaller" value="Make Images Smaller" />
        <div class="images">
            <img src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/fruits-images/fruits-images-4.jpg" />
            <img src="http://blogs.extension.iastate.edu/foodsavings/files/2014/06/vegetables-variety.jpg" />
            <img src="http://gilowveld.sites.caxton.co.za/wp-content/uploads/sites/97/2016/03/Dairy-products.jpg" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```